# Scaling data in RFECV with scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

It is common to scale the training and testing data separately before training and predicting progress of a classification task.

I want to embed the aforementioned process in `RFECV` which runs CV tests thus I tried the following:

Do
`X_scaled = preprocessing.scale(X)` in the first place, where `X` is the whole data set. By doing so, training and testing data are not scaled separately, which is not considered.

The other way I tried is to pass:

```
scaling_svm = Pipeline([('scaler', preprocessing.StandardScaler()),
                        ('svm',LinearSVC(penalty=penalty, dual=False, class_weight='auto'))])
```

as parameter to the argument in `RFECV` :

```
rfecv = RFECV(estimator=scaling_svm, step=1, cv=StratifiedKFold(y, 7),
                  scoring=score, verbose=0)
```

However, I got an error since `RFECV` needs the `estimator` to have attribute `.coef_`. 
What should I suppose to do? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, admittedly, but if anyone is interested you can create a customised pipeline as follows:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
class RfePipeline(Pipeline):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.coef_
```

And then replace `Pipeline` with `RfePipeline` in your code.

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51412845/1453508).