# best-found PCA estimator to be used as the estimator in RFECV

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, feature-extraction, feature-selection

This works (mostly from the demo sample at sklearn):

```
print(__doc__)


# Code source: Gaël Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause


import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn import linear_model, decomposition, datasets
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from scipy.stats import uniform

lregress = LinearRegression()

pca = decomposition.PCA()
pipe = Pipeline(steps=[('pca', pca), ('regress', lregress)])


# Plot the PCA spectrum
pca.fit(data_num)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(16, 9))
plt.clf()
plt.axes([.2, .2, .7, .7])
plt.plot(pca.explained_variance_, linewidth=2)
plt.axis('tight')
plt.xlabel('n_components')
plt.ylabel('explained_variance_')

# Prediction
n_components = uniform.rvs(loc=1, scale=data_num.shape[1], size=50, 
random_state=42).astype(int)

# Parameters of pipelines can be set using ‘__’ separated parameter names:
estimator_pca = GridSearchCV(pipe,
                         dict(pca__n_components=n_components)
                        )
estimator_pca.fit(data_num, data_labels)

plt.axvline(estimator_pca.best_estimator_.named_steps['pca'].n_components,
            linestyle=':', label='n_components chosen ' + 
str(estimator_pca.best_estimator_.named_steps['pca'].n_components))
plt.legend(prop=dict(size=12))


plt.plot(np.cumsum(pca.explained_variance_ratio_), linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

And this works:

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFECV


estimator = LinearRegression()
selector = RFECV(estimator, step=1, cv=5, scoring='explained_variance')
selector = selector.fit(data_num_pd, data_labels)
print("Selected number of features : %d" % selector.n_features_)

plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score")
plt.plot(range(1, len(selector.grid_scores_) + 1), selector.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

but this gives me the error "RuntimeError: The classifier does not expose "coef_" or "feature_importances_" attributes" on the line "selector1 = selector1.fit"

```
pca_est = estimator_pca.best_estimator_

selector1 = RFECV(pca_est, step=1, cv=5, scoring='explained_variance')
selector1 = selector1.fit(data_num_pd, data_labels)

print("Selected number of features : %d" % selector1.n_features_)

plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score")
plt.plot(range(1, len(selector1.grid_scores_) + 1), selector1.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

How do I get my best-found PCA estimator to be used as the estimator in RFECV?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue in pipeline design. Refer to [the github page here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/wiki/Pipeline-et-al.-design-issues#accessing-fitted-attributes-cf-2561-2568-2630-wrt-pipeline):

> ## Accessing fitted attributes:
>
> Moreover, some fitted attributes are used by meta-estimators;
>   AdaBoostClassifier assumes its sub-estimator has a classes_ attribute
>   after fitting, which means that presently Pipeline cannot be used as
>   the sub-estimator of AdaBoostClassifier.
>
> Either meta-estimators such as AdaBoostClassifier need to be
>   configurable in how they access this attribute, or meta-estimators
>   such as Pipeline need to make some fitted attributes of sub-estimators
>   accessible.

Same goes for other attributes like `coef_` and `feature_importances_`. They are parts of last estimator so not exposed by pipeline.

Now you can try to follow the last para here and try to circumvent this to include it in pipeline, by doing something like this:

```
class Mypipeline(Pipeline):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.coef_
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.feature_importances_
```

And then using this new pipeline class in your code instead of original `Pipeline`.

This should work in most cases but not yours. You are doing feature reduction using PCA inside the pipeline. But want to do feature selection using RFECV. This in my opinion is not a good combination.

RFECV will keep on decreasing the number of features to be used. But the `n_components` in your best selected pca from above grid-search will be fixed. Then it will again throw an error when number of features become less than `n_components`. You cannot do anything in that case.

So I would advise you to think over your use case and code.

Comment: Thanks - I understand and agree.