# How to use sklearn RFECV to select the optimal features to pass to a dimensionality reduction step before fitting my estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-discriminant

How can I use sklearn RFECV method to select the optimal features to pass to a LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2) method for dimensionality reduction, before fitting my estimator using a KNN.

```
pipeline = make_pipeline(Normalizer(), LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2), KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=10))

X = self.dataset
y = self.postures

min_features_to_select = 1  # Minimum number of features to consider
rfecv = RFECV(svc, step=1, cv=None, scoring='f1_weighted', min_features_to_select=min_features_to_select)

rfecv.fit(X, y)

print(rfecv.support_)
print(rfecv.ranking_)
print("Optimal number of features : %d" % rfecv.n_features_)

Plot number of features VS. cross-validation scores
plt.figure()
plt.xlabel("Number of features selected")
plt.ylabel("Cross validation score (nb of correct classifications)")
plt.plot(range(min_features_to_select,
len(rfecv.grid_scores_) + min_features_to_select),
rfecv.grid_scores_)
plt.show()
```

I get the following error from this code. If I run this code without the LinearDiscriminantAnalysis() step then it works, but this an important part of my processing.

```
*** ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator Pipeline should have `coef_` or `feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before calling transform.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach has an overall problem: the `KNeighborsClassifier` does not have an intrinsic measure of feature importance. Thus, it is not compatible with `RFECV` as its documentation states about the classifier:

> A supervised learning estimator with a fit method that provides information about feature importance either through a coef_ attribute or through a feature_importances_ attribute.

You will definitely fail with `KNeighborsClassifier`. You definitely need another classifier like `RandomForestClassifier` or `SVC`.

If you can shoose another classifier, your pipeline still needs to expose the feature importance of the estimator in your pipeline. For this you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412845/best-found-pca-estimator-to-be-used-as-the-estimator-in-rfecv/51418655#51418655) here which defines a custom pipeline for this purpose:

```
class Mypipeline(Pipeline):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.coef_
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.feature_importances_
```

Define your pipeline like:

```
pipeline = MyPipeline([
    ('normalizer', Normalizer()),
    ('ldm', LinearDiscriminantAnalysis(n_components=2)),
    ('rf', RandomForestClassifier())
])
```

and it should work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough. I don't know how to get RFECV to work using the pipeline in my code. I keep getting the values error displayed above. However, if I don't include the LinearDiscriminantAnalysis() step it does work.

Comment: But then your approach is all in naught since `KNeighborsClassifier` does not have an intrinsic feature importance measure. You need a classifier that can compute such a measure in order to use `RFECV`.

Comment: You may have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks you that makes sense now