# Using SKLearn's Pipeline with RFECV feature selection on a regression problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to perform feature selection on some spectroscopy data using SKLearn's `RFECV` function. I want to use a pipeline with PLSRegression as its last step, as the `estimator` for the `RFECV` function. However I'm getting different (clearly wrong) results when using `PLSRegression` in a pipeline, versus just on its own. Error details and minimum repeatable examples below.

1. Imports and setup

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Use Github data from NIRPY blog as sample data - using NIR spectra to predict peach brix values
df = pd.read_csv(r'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nevernervous78/nirpyresearch/master/data/peach_spectra_brix.csv')
X = df.iloc[:,1:].values
y = df.iloc[:,0].values
```

2. First, doing the RFECV with a normal PLSRegression object, to show what I'm expecting.

```
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=3)
selector = RFECV(pls, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]), # Don't remove too many wavelengths
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')
selector = selector.fit(X, y)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(selector.ranking_)
plt.show()
```

Which yields this plot, with all the rank=1 wavelengths being selected by the algorithm in different regions of the spectrum, as expected:

[image: PLSRegression ranking]

3. However the real data I'm analyzing will be sent through a pipeline with various steps, the last of which is a PLSRegression object. So trying this with a typical SKLearn pipeline, with PLS as the only step for simplicity here:

```
pipe = Pipeline([('pls', PLSRegression(n_components=3))])

selector2 = RFECV(pipe, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')
selector2 = selector2.fit(X, y)
```

But this yields an error:

```
ValueError: when `importance_getter=='auto'`, the underlying estimator Pipeline should have `coef_` or
`feature_importances_` attribute. Either pass a fitted estimator to feature selector or call fit before
calling transform.
```

3. So I found a potential workaround to give my Pipeline class a coef_ attribute, per [best-found PCA estimator to be used as the estimator in RFECV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51412845/best-found-pca-estimator-to-be-used-as-the-estimator-in-rfecv/51418655#51418655) :

```
class Mypipeline(Pipeline):
    @property
    def coef_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.coef_
    @property
    def feature_importances_(self):
        return self._final_estimator.feature_importances_

mypipe = Mypipeline([('pls', PLSRegression(n_components=3))])

selector3 = RFECV(mypipe, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=-2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error')
selector3 = selector3.fit(X, y)
```

On the bright side, we've avoided the error. On the not so bright side, the wavelengths have been ranked sequentially in descending order so the last `2*np.shape(X)[0]` features are used, and the rest ignored. The ranking plot looks like this:

[image: Ranking from using a custom pipeline]

Which is clearly wrong.

4. My next attempt tried to make use of the `importance_getter` parameter instead, as described in the docs for the RFECV function:

```
selector4 = RFECV(pipe, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=-2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                 importance_getter=pipe.named_steps.pls.coef_)
selector4 = selector4.fit(X, y)
```

But of course pipe wasn't fitted yet so I get another error, `AttributeError: 'PLSRegression' object has no attribute '_coef_'`.

5. Ok, maybe I need to fit pipe before using it with the selector?

```
pipe = Pipeline([('pls', PLSRegression(n_components=3))])
pipe.fit(X, y)
selector5 = RFECV(pipe, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=-2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                 importance_getter=pipe.named_steps.pls.coef_)
selector5 = selector5.fit(X, y)
```

Nope, new error:

```
ValueError: `importance_getter` has to be a string or `callable`
```

6. So maybe make importance_getter into a function?

```
def importance_getter(pipe):
    return pipe.named_steps.pls.coef_

pipe = Pipeline([('pls', PLSRegression(n_components=3))])

pipe.fit(X, y)

selector6 = RFECV(pipe, 
                 step=1, 
                 cv=5, 
                 verbose=0, 
                 n_jobs=-2, 
                 min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
                 scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
                 importance_getter=importance_getter(pipe))

selector6 = selector6.fit(X, y)
```

Which returns the same error as (5). Long story short I need help figuring out how to do this properly!

Thanks

Comment: Update: I read the docs again and noticed the `named_steps.pls.coef_` for `importance_getter` should actually be passed as a string, so I tried that that but got the same results as (3):
```pipe = Pipeline([('pls', PLSRegression(n_components=3))])
pipe.fit(X, y)
selector7 = RFECV(pipe, 
step=1, 
cv=5, 
verbose=0, 
n_jobs=2, 
min_features_to_select=(2*np.shape(X)[0]),
scoring='neg_root_mean_squared_error',
 importance_getter='named_steps.pls.coef_')
selector7 = selector7.fit(X, y)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(selector7.ranking_)
plt.show()
```